# await on long service call behaves differently in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, httpclient, botframework, long-running-processes, coveo

I have two dialogs called from root dialog based on the prompt response.
Both dialogs internally prepare request and call a service class. Weird thing is one dialog resumes with response from service but the other though receives response from service is not resuming.

Below method works fine and resumes the call at `if (searchResult != null && searchResult.Item1 != null)`

```
public virtual async Task MessageRecievedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;
    if (message.Text == "quit")
    {
        context.Done<object>(null);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            var srm = new CoveoRestSearchService.CoveoSearchRequestModel
            {
                Query = message.Text,
                EnableDidYouMean = true,
                QuerySource = CoveoRestSearchService.Constants.SWEATERSSOURCE
            };
            var searchResult = await csp.PerformSearch(srm);
            if (searchResult != null && searchResult.Item1 != null)
            {
                await CardUtil.showHeroCard(message, searchResult.Item1);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"No search results for {message.Text} found");
            }
            await PostSearchUsageAnalyticsToCoveo(context, srm, searchResult.Item2);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error when searching : {e.Message}");
        }
        finally {
            context.Wait(MessageRecievedAsync);
        }                
    }
}
```

This below one though looks identical is not resuming the `if (response != null)`

```
public virtual async Task MessageRecievedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;
    if (message.Text == "quit")
    {
        context.Done<object>(null);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            string toDate = currentDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
            string fromDate = currentDate.AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
            MetricsQuery = MetricsQuery.Replace("{fromISODate}", fromDate);
            MetricsQuery = MetricsQuery.Replace("{toISODate}", toDate);
            MetricsQuery = MetricsQuery.Replace("{term}", message.Text);
            var response = await cuawc.MetricSearchUsageToCoveoAsync(MetricsQuery
                .Replace(" ", "%20")
                .Replace("!=", "!%3D")
                .Replace("==", "%3D%3D")
                .Replace(":", "%3A"));
            if (response != null)
            {
                var message_from_bot = context.MakeMessage();
            }
            //message_from_bot.Attachments = new List<Attachments>();
            await context.PostAsync("Please enter the search term for metrics");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error when pulling metrics : {e.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Wait(MessageRecievedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

Struggling from past 2 days to figure what is wrong!!

Comment: Found the issue.. the ObjectType defined in Task is not the one I was returning. I used a 'dynamic' variable to serialize the response and returned.
`public async Task<object> SendSearchEventToCoveoUAAsync(string queryString)`